# How to apply this kind of spot gradient on live text in photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image]

I just got stucked how to apply partical gradient effect on this texts.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried adding a layer style with a gradient overlay effect, set to a radial gradient?